# Problem with truffle deployment in ropsten

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-deployment

I followed [tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider) and add result this tutorial on [git](https://github.com/poperechnyi1/TruffleDeploy)

When I trying deploy my contract via command:  `truffle migrate --network ropsten`

I have error:
[image]

How fix this gub?

Comment: Did you `npm install` the required dependencies? From your stack trace it seems the dependency _scrypt.js_ is missing. Some dependencies need a c++ compiler for that you may need this https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools. Also try upgrading your node version, I'm using v8.6 without issues on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy this contract in enother way:

```
function sendRaw(rawTx) {
    var privateKey = new Buffer(key, 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(privateKey);
    var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(
    '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

var rawTx = {
    nonce: web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)),
    gasLimit: web3.toHex(1500000),
    gasPrice: web3.toHex(80000000),
    data: bytecode 
};
sendRaw(rawTx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I runed command npm init,  add dependencies of project:

```
    {
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Deploy smart-contract via truffle",
  "main": "truffle.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bip39": "^2.4.0",
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "^0.6.0",
    "web3-provider-engine": "^13.3.3",
    "hdkey": "latest",
    "web3": "latest" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start" : "node truffle.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/poperechnyi1/TruffleDeploy.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/poperechnyi1/TruffleDeploy/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/poperechnyi1/TruffleDeploy#readme"
}
```

Then I runed coomand npm install and npm start. 
And I have error:
[image]

I use npm version 3.10.10 and nove version v6.11.5.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install scrypt.js --save`  
This is not a truffle error, you need to install all the modules being used in the project. Let me know if it worked. Thanks !